# Permission of parents to be a Monk

Tags: theravada, early-buddhism

I already know this much    https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/35802/17220
Still ,there is a particular case where ,I have no experience/knowledge which is below.

Person with 27 yrs. of age and above. Parents are alive. No responsibility over Person. Person is having **exemplary character & is unmarried. Person is unsatisfied by any meditation center , monastery , ashram , yogi etc. ,so want to meditate alone in forest alongside other *religious meditators.** Parents are not ready to accept buddha or buddha's teachings for their child cause they think that it(buddhism) is only to destroy householdness. It tears down parents if person flees away to forest or even tries to do so.

**Update**

Under these circumstances, is permission required **,if yes ,then how to convince parents.**

**Note::** 'To be a monk' means 'to go forth to be' ::

detached one , beyond all sense of his own name and form. Without any existence of I, my or mine. Not to grieve if his name and form entity were to decay and deteriorate.

Comment: [FAQ’s about a monk](https://sasanarakkha.org/2003/06/01/faqs-about-a-monk/) may give inspirations.

Comment: Another related discussion: [Q&A Permission of your parents in your renunciation](http://sangham.net/index.php/topic,8409.msg13979.html#msg13979)

Answer (score 1):

This rule is put in place because joining a monastic order (like any thing else one does in life) is a karmic act, and one should strive not to do harm. The idea that a child might disappear into a monastic order, never accomplishing any of the 'normal' things that parents expect of children — gainful employment, grandchildren, social status or respect, or any of the other hallmarks of worldly 'success' — can be frightening and disturbing to a parent. One is asked to seek parent's permission so that one does not enter monastic life leaving a cloud of fear and resentment in one's wake. It's an act of compassion for parents and the world they live in.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to find a monestary that will let that slide. Some are more flexable and take the rules as guidelines instead of law to be followed rigidly, not out of laziness but out of wise practicality and out of an attempt at a sense of what the Buddha might do in today's times.

Also relentlessness in your dedication to break into the monkhood is often a help as they like to  know you are serious.

Comment: Exactly , it is possible to find a friend that will help in letting this slide. Still ,tears won't stop .what to do now?how to make parents ready?cause there would be no further contact after going for deep meditation.Should one proceed like Gautama & mahaveera jain before enlightenment. If one tries to do so , it tears down parents.

Comment: Wow, no furthur contact forever? You know, monks can go see their parents and even their spouse and kids but when in deep training it is obviously frowned upon. Have you been to any 10 day(or more) meditation retreats first? Have you given any thought to becoming an Anagarika?

Comment: Nope , remember ,monk - noble word ,so, noble behaviour (1st characterstic :: same behaviour to All). So , no spouse , no child , no parent . One will be called a monk ... please refer Verse 367 , Chapter 25 ,dhammapada .

Comment: Noble behavior does not mean  having  extreme views. The Monastic code allows you to visit your parents. Do you believe your mind will never be able to be vigilant and undistracted around your parents? Letting go of your parents doesn't mean you reject them, it means you stop attaching to them.  Love is not attatchment.

Comment: I suggest being around noble friends at monestaries for awhile and listening to them before ordaining. Ask them what the process was like for them and if they have any advice. I think most likely they will respect such questions and think you are a wise student. Whatever you are going through they are likely to relate as they were where you are at one time.

Comment: What does ,"having *extreme* views" mean for a Noble one? Noble Behaviour comes first then Noble Word is given to such warrior. In question ,"to be a monk" means  ,"to go forth to be a *detached* one" .After one becomes a detached-one , Monk is used in front of that  mighty warrior's name.

Comment: Problem is ,I couldn't find *Noble Friend .Well ,whatever the case is ... Ok! Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0):

> Person is unsatisfied by any meditation center , monastery , ashram , yogi etc. ,so want to meditate alone in forest alongside other *religious meditators.

Then he isn't immediately seeking an ordination as that would usually entail integrating into an existing group for which such an allowance is to be obtained.

I hope the person figures out a good solution ensuring a comfortable & safe abiding; not subjecting themselves to unnecessary hardship and stress.

It is going to be difficult to be a yogi without ordination because going forth in the dispensation of Buddha Gotama without a formal ordination is very uncommon. As it is, it is often asked of one to complete a trial period before being given a formal going forth which is like a meal ticket to an extent.

Imo a yogi without formal association is more likely to be assumed to be an outcast holding wrong views, unable to get along with 'the contemporary masters'. Therefore it will be difficult lest one makes a living recycling stuff or otherwise gets the money.

Comment: How about lay people without formal association? Without Name and face? How are they assumed?

Comment: @SamanaJohann I don't know about other countries ,but in India/Nepal :: if person is financially poor ,he/she is considered to be lower caste by 'people following caste system' and an idiot by others. If person is powerful or rich , no objections/obligations against/to such person in public will be made. Only 1 in 1lakh would respect such person in India/Nepal.

Comment: So is it mostly under Brahmans in India, Europe US and everywhere: But what is really an outcast, Brahman @TempoItan ? [Vasala Sutta: Discourse on Outcasts](http://accesstoinsight.eu/en/tipitaka/sut/kn/snp/snp.1.07.piya) Geatings from an "Outcast"

Comment: @SamanaJohann this false behaviour/thinking is of all upper-castes towards such lay person. I know this story of outcast; just gave situation in India. Moreover ,I don't call anyone(even if buddha suggested to brahmin) as an outcast ... I call them more Ignorant than me ...cause... at some point ,I was also more Ignorant than anyone else that's why I have not attained Nibbana till now. Nice talk.÷)

Comment: It's good to know right and wrong, good to reflect for oneself and strive for beyond and encourage others toward the Noble Domain, Brahman @TempoItan . Not is it, that a real Brahman should considered equal anyway and sacrifices upwardly is necessary for escape the dusty life in households.

Comment: Nepalese consider mother even higher as heaven, Brahma, already. But that's the way of communisms ideals applied in common sociaty, pulling each other down, as a matter of biased opposite.

Comment: @SamanaJohann Please , I request not to call me brahman. Because Buddha ,in dhammapada says, brahman is Buddha. I am not buddha ,just an ignorant one and don't consider anybody(including youself) as an outcast. We all are same Untill enlightenment and will be same post enlightenment... because even a small amount of ignorance is responsible to put in endless cycle of suffering.

Comment: Brahman is an adressing for a person from good family and stand. The Buddha didn't avoid but used this adressing also for Brahmans and their sons in common societies. No, nobody is equal another, but some have reached the stream, and some finished the task. Only Arahats can therefor be called equal in their qualities, end even they respect the difference between beings. The is no refuge if doing such toward equality but just stagnation.

Comment: Equality on basis of ,"Ignorance is still present" without consideration of ,"Next Birth". Within this birth, Untill state of no-ignorance is reached ,we are equal. Post enlightenment , as new birth within remaining age of this birth, they will be same. I haven't met buddha or Arhant ,so can't tell what they respect & what not but as far as ,'I have seen sages' ,they treat everyone as equal--without any respect/disrespect(a worldly concern) towards anyone.

Comment: @SamanaJohann  these sages were not enlightened ,this, they themselves accepted so might be I am wrong ,still above is what's present within deeps of my mind about Arhant. Thanks for guidance & appreciation.

Comment: I assume that lay people can go forth without ordination and are to that extent Bhikkhus like Ven Pukkusati.

Answer (score 0):

**It tears down parents if person flees away to forest or even tries to do so.**
It seems person is having very strong bond/attachment with h-is/er caring parents.

**Parents are not ready to accept buddha or buddha's teachings for their child cause they think that it(buddhism) is only to destroy householdness.**
That's an obvious reaction from parents who have not been established in dhamma or they are established but worry about person's capability. Even buddha used to question, when his disciple/s want to go to dangerous/full-of-`dukkha` places to preach like with the case of 'poorna'.
`Moral::` You will have to prove in front of them that you are worthy of independent homelessness.

**Under these circumstances, is permission required ,if yes ,then how to convince parents.**
Surely, there is a way for someone aspiring to be established on Noble 8 fold path, a 'middle path'.

If parents are very caring, person might start by bearing his own responsibility first, slowly-slowly increasing independent-meditation-time, slowly-slowly showing parents about his/her calibur of `asceticness` and decision making capability.
Wait for the right time, start reducing any communication-gap among relation.
No caring parent wants to harm his/her child or to be a cause for any harm. It's just the `worriness about safety` that they `pretend to act as a barrier`. Understanding them from their perspective will enable person to see/feel them as `Helpers in person's decision`.

`If parents are not so caring`, then `tears` might be out of society-fear but such perception requires one to be very hard-hearted.
In this case, person must make his stand in society first. Person should start by bearing his own responsibility first••• same-as-before ••• decision making capability, ultimately leading him/her to win over everyone's ego.
Wait for the right time, start reducing any communication-gap among relation and society.

With right time and right understanding, person will surely be able to take his/her decision of independent-meditation(asceticness).